# Performance & security impact of enabling grpc server reflection

Tags: grpc, grpc-java

I want to know what would be the impact on performance of server on enabling server reflection & if there are any security concerns with it.

Answer (score 2):

Reflection service couldn't impact performance, other than the memory it uses to track the reflection data. Depending on the language/implementation, the reflection service may be able to dump protobuf descriptors (which does not include comments) for *any* protobuf used in the binary. Whether that is a concern depends on your environment and service.

It is common to have it enabled all-the-time for internal services. When you have a reverse proxy that contacts multiple services depending on the path, the service is generally not exposed as you'd need a smart implementation that combines results from multiple backends and the proxy's configuration.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Is there any grpc documentation for the performance or security impacts with enabling server reflection? Can you please share

Comment: Also for which language does the reflection service maybe able to dump protobuf descriptors?